# Pandas's dataframe becoming empty after removing empty rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data set:

```
     Survived  Not Survived
0         NaN          22.0
1        38.0           NaN
2        26.0           NaN
3        35.0           NaN
4         NaN          35.0
..        ...           ...
886       NaN          27.0
887      19.0           NaN
888       NaN           NaN
889      26.0           NaN
890       NaN          32.0
```

I want to remove all the rows which contains NaN so i wrote the following code(the dataset's name is titanic_feature_data):

```
titanic_feature_data = titanic_feature_data.dropna()
```

And when i try to display the new dataset i get the following result:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Survived, Not Survived]
Index: []
```

What's the problem ? and how can i fix it ?

Comment: From what I can see every row contains a NaN. So removing all rows with NaN values will mean you don't have any rows left....

Comment: what  you expecting as output

Comment: `dropna` is not a good strategy for the titanic dataset.

Comment: @ruby  it's weird, in the original dataset more than 700 rows don't contain NaN

Comment: @komatiraju032   the same data set without missing values.

Comment: @GardeDesOmbres, if the original dataset has rows that don't contain NaN, how are you reading the data in?

Comment: @ruby i didn't understand what you wanna say. Can you reformulate, please ?

Comment: @GardeDesOmbres if you want same data without missing you can replace those values with mean or something else

Comment: Sure. Firstly, where did you get the data from and how did you read it into the dataframe? Secondly, when you say the original data has more than 700 rows that don't contain NaN, are you talking about your titanic_feature_data dataframe, or the place where you downloaded the data from?

Comment: @ruby i got the dataset from kaggle, it's a csv file so i used `read_csv` method to read it. When i said that the original contains more than 700 rows without NaN i mean the data set i downloaded from kaggle.

Comment: if it's a public dataset can we have the link?

Comment: @ruby  (https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data) it's `train.csv'

Answer (score 0):

By using `titanic_feature_data.dropna()`, you are removing all rows with at least one missing value. From the data you printed in your question, it looks like all rows contains at least one missing value. Is it possible that simply all your rows contains at least one missing value? If so, it makes total sense that your dataframe is empty after `dropna()`, right?

Having said that, perhaps you are looking to drop rows that have a missing value for one particular column, for example column `Not Survived`. Then you could use:

```
titanic_feature_data.dropna(subset='Not Survived')
```

Also, if you are confused about why certain rows are dropped, I recommend checking for missing values explicitly first, without dropping them. That way you can see which instances *would have been dropped*:

```
incomplete_rows = titanic_feature_data.isnull().any(axis=1)
```

`incomplete_rows` is a boolean series, which indicates whether a row contains any missing value or not. You can use this series to subset your dataframe and see which rows contain missing values (presumably all of them, given your example)

```
titanic_feature_data.loc[incomplete_rows, :]
```